# Where Are the Code Snippets for Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, code-snippets

For WPF/C# where are all the default code snippets for things like Dependency Properties (wpfdp) or Routed Commands (wpfrc). I couldn't find these snippets listed anywhere in Visual Studio.

Comment: `prop` then Tab or Enter gives you property, `propfull` gives you property with a backing field, `propdp` Dependency Property. I would avoid using `RoutedCommands` as they were not designed to be used with MvvM use either RelayCommand or a `DelegateCommand`. They are much easier to use and much more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a dependency property, use `propdp`.

You can find out all available snippets easily if you're using visual studio 2017:

1. Type a letter, for example `a`.
2. Click on the last icon at the bottom of the [Intellisense Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0XN.png).
3. This displays all available snippets.

Comment: Thanks. It was under a snippet folder called NetFX30 (whatever that means). Both the snippet and the folder are named differently in VB so when I didn't see a "WPF" snippet folder I assumed it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's wise to learn c# if you're trying to learn wpf. WPF has a notoriously tricky learning curve and you will want all the help you can get in the process. C# developers are much more active blogging and posting samples than VB. It's way easier to find C# help. Certainly in my area of the world it's also way easier to find work using c# than vb.

There's a snippet manager.
Press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B and you get a window up.
They are organised by language.
You can write your own fairly easily, although the support in standard vs is pretty limited.
Some people particularly like resharper for it's macro snippet support.
Roslyn supports refactoring and some prefer that route for complicated snippet-like functionality.

But anyhow, take a look in there.
Under c# do you not see the snippets?
If not this could be an install issue.
Maybe you installed just for VB initially if you're moving to c#.
And as Xanimax said. Set routed command aside for now. Learn MVVM and pick one of the nuget packages intended to give you a more convenient way to define commands. I like mvvmlight.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I actually already know WPF and I'm learning C# as an alternative to VB so I can work in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard commands are `propdp` and `propa`. If you need to find them otherwise type in <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>X</kbd> and the `Insert Snippet` dialog will pop up and you will be given the list of keyboard snippets to insert via folders:

[image]

The two you are interested in are in the `NetFX30` folder and not the `Visual C#` folder:

[image]